# SQL Removing Subsets from the same table

Tags: sql, subset

I've tried looking this up on similar questions but they don't seem to be equivalent.

I'm trying to remove smaller subset groups from a table no matter the order of the values in the group. So keep the larger group and remove smaller groups as long as they are subsets of the larger one.

```
Group   Item
1       A
1       B
1       C
1       D
2        B
2        A
3       B
3       E
3       A
4        Z
4        W
4        Y
```

In this example since group 1 is largest, i want to keep it. I'd also want to keep group 4 as it isn't a subset of another group. But I want to REMOVE group 2 (as it's a subset of group 1) but not remove group 3 (since it is not a full subset).

I'll also mention that the data is massive and there is no way to determine what the "item" or "group" value will be, so I can't make queries with specific values.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the pairs of parent and child groups as:

```
select t1.group as parent_group, t2.group as childgroup
from t t2 left join
     t t1
     on t1.item = t2.item and t1.group <> t2.group
group by t1.group, t2.group
having count(t1.item) = (select count(*) from t tt1 where tt1.group = t1.group);
```

This checks that everything in the child (`t2`) is in the parent (`t1`).

If you know that no groups are identical, then you can just delete all the child groups.  If they can be identical, then change the `having` to:

```
having count(t1.item) = (select count(*) from t tt1 where tt1.group = t1.group) and
       count(*) <> count(t1.item)   -- not an exact match
```

Comment: Thank you! At first glance this looks like it will work for me. Though when looking at the tables, it looks like the parent and child group are backwards and using a left join gives null values in parents so I can't check. 
I switch child and parent and used a join and now the child does seem to show all the subsets that would need to be deleted. I'll go through more of the results to be sure they are correct.

Comment: That did indeed work out with those changes. Thank you again!

Comment: @RuttleHead . . . Do you want to edit the answer with those changes?